# Django Form does not Render in web page

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a post edit page in Django, but when I test it the form does not render, only the submit button. There are no input fields displayed on the page.

There are no errors given when I run the server or load the page.

Here is my code:

View:

```
@login_required
def updateview(request, pk):
if request.method == "POST":
    instance = get_object_or_404(Listing, tag=pk)
    updateform = ListingUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
    if updateform.is_valid():
        updateform.save()
        listing = updateform.instance
        messages.success(request, "New Listing Created")
        return redirect(reverse('main:listingdetails', kwargs={'pk': listing.tag}))
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Please correct the error below.')

updateform = ListingUpdateForm
return render(request,
            "main/createlisting.html",
            context={"updateform":updateform})
```

Template:

```
{% block content %}

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{updateform}}

    <button type="submit">post</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Form:

```
class ListingUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
countryList = (("US", "United States"),
    ("UK", "United Kingdom"))

country = forms.ChoiceField(choices=countryList)

class Meta:
    model = Listing
    fields = ('title', 'description', 'price', 'country')
```

URLs:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", ListingListView.as_view(), name="homepage"),
    path("register/", views.register, name="register"),
    path("logout/", views.logout_request, name="logout"),
    path("login/", views.login_request, name="login"),
    path("updateprofile/", views.updateprofile, name="updateprofile"),
    path("listing/<uuid:pk>/", ListingDetailView.as_view(), name='listingdetails'),
    path("listing/create/", views.createview, name='listingcreate'),
    path("listing/<uuid:pk>/update/", views.updateview, name='postupdate'),
    path("profile/<username>/", views.profile, name='profile'),

]
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is this the "root" `urls.py` or are there other `urls.py`? It looks like the the url patterns of another app are checked before the `postupdate`.

Comment: Yes, I used include() in the 'root' to refer to this, which is in the 'main' folder. I don't think that's the issue since all my other urls work fine.

Comment: It looks to me that the `createview` is the one not being triggered, not the `updateview`. You should put the `createview` (`listingcreate`) before the `listingdetails`.

Comment: Do you mean move the 'listingcreate' line before the 'listingdetails' line? If so, I did that and the form still doesn't render.

Comment: with what URL do you work?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: what URL do you request to get the update form, what is in the URL bar to visit that page?

Comment: /listing/0142aff4-aabf-4734-9794-8cd42bcc914b/update/ The UUID is the primary key of the listing that I'm testing this on.

Comment: did you by any chance defined the `updateview` *twice* in the `views.py`, such that only the last one is retained?

Comment: No, there is only one updateview.

Comment: Why is the template `main/createlisting.html`? Perhaps you render the wrong template? If the `createlisting.html` template contains a `{{ createform }}`, then this will not render if you pass data as `{{ updateform }}`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks for the help man.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a GET request, you should create a form object. You should furthermore only redirect in case of a *successful* POST request, and rerender the form in case it is not valid, that way, Django can render errors next to the form items:

```
@login_required
def updateview(request, pk):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Listing, tag=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        updateform = ListingUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if updateform.is_valid():
            listing = updateform.save()
            return redirect('main:listingdetails', pk=listing.pk)
    else:
        updateform = ListingUpdateForm(instance=instance)
    return render(
        request,
        'main/createlisting.html',
        context={'updateform': updateform}
    )
```

Comment: Thanks, but that hasn't worked, the form's not rendering and there's still no error given. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @SirBlender: are you sure that you are triggering the correct view? What if you add a `print(..)` statement at the top (before `instance = ...`), does it print something, otherwise there is a problem with the URL patterns.

Comment: Nothing is printed, so there must be an issue with urls like you said, but I can't see what it is. I added my url patterns to the original post, the updateview is second from bottom.